# How to add c++ code in Wordpress.com post

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to add some c++ code in WordPress post, but some character become &lt/&amp/&gt.

How can I solve this problem?

I tried the following:

```
[sourcecode language="cpp" title="Code:"]
void build_LCP_array(void)
{
    LCP[0] = 0;
    int n = text.size(), i, j, id1, id2;
    for(i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        id1 = arr[i - 1].indx;
        id2 = arr[i].indx;
        LCP[i] = 0;
        for(j = step - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            if(Rank[j][id1] == Rank[j][id2] && Rank[j][id2])
            {
                LCP[i] += (1 << j);
                id1 += (1 << j);
                id2 += (1 << j);
            }
    }
}
[/sourcecode]
```

And Result:

```
void build_LCP_array(void)
{
    LCP[0] = 0;
    int n = text.size(), i, j, id1, id2;
    for(i = 1; i &lt; n; i++)
    {
        id1 = arr[i - 1].indx;
        id2 = arr[i].indx;
        LCP[i] = 0;
        for(j = step - 1; j &gt;= 0; j--)
            if(Rank[j][id1] == Rank[j][id2] &amp;&amp; Rank[j][id2])
            {
                LCP[i] += (1 &lt;&lt; j);
                id1 += (1 &lt;&lt; j);
                id2 += (1 &lt;&lt; j);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you wanting just to show the code (<pre><code>) etc or to have syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better way to post code in WordPress using [gist](https://gist.github.com/).
Create a public gist of your code, and copy the source link and paste to WordPress content.

Answer (score 2):

According to here: http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/ , you should use

> [code language="cpp"] your code here [/code]

Try this plugin too: https://wordpress.org/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/

Comment: [code language="cpp"] your code here [/code] m also trying this way but getting same result. And my blog isn't self hosting, so i have no plugins using option.

Comment: Bear in mind that advice is for a hosted WordPress blog at wordpress.com, and much of it won't apply to WordPress hosted elsewhere.

Comment: @mattgibson noticed. But still he can install plugin from admin dashboard.

Comment: Wordpress' support for C++ is garbage. Might be better to use a preformatted block rather than deal with it trying  to transform `template <class T>` into some kind of HTML tag